# Geometric markings in the text for line segments and angles

Tags: accents, technical-drawing

I am looking for commands that puts marks for line segments, angles, and other geometrical entities around letters in a text. Many geometry books use a line segment with dots at the end and place it over two letters to indicate a particular line segment.  Same for an arc between two points on a circle.  Plain LaTeX does not allow for this.  A package must be downloaded. Please give me these commands and the commands for the symbols for angles, triangle, and parallel lines.

Comment: Have a look at the [`tkz-euclide`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide) package.

Comment: Are we talking math mode text?  Like $\angle ABC$ or $\overbar{AB}$.  Arc symbols can get generated using \stackrel, \frown and possibly \resizebox from the \graphics or \graphicx packages.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina, I clicked on the link tkz-euclide. The web site "http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide" appeared on the screen. The only manual there is written in French, and I do not speak French. Is there a manual written in English?

Comment: @John Kormylo, I would like to use these commands in math mode (within text).  The \overbar command does not give the dots at the endpoints. I looked on various web sites for using the \resizebox command. Every instance that I found involved tables. Can you give me the code for typesetting "$arc{AB}$ is an arc on a unit circle centered at the origin"? Do I need to have "\usepackage{graphics}" in the preamble?

Comment: @user60254 No; the only manual I know of for `tkz-euclide` is the one in French.

Comment: What you want is a arrow using round arrowheads (on both sides).  There is probably something like that out there.  I've always just used \overbar for line segments.

Comment: I have only seen the commands "\bar", "\overbar", and "\overline" used in LaTeX to convey line segments. Since this is the mark used to convey conjugates of complex numbers, I would have preferred to have used a different mark to convey line segments.

Comment: the tag [tex-core] isn't appropriate for this.  i've added [accents].  i'm not sure that's really the best either, but i think it's closer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do arc symbols

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphics}

\newlength{\tempa}

\newcommand{\arc}[1]% #1=symbols, as in \arc{AB}
{\begingroup% preserve \tempa
\settowidth{\tempa}{$#1$}%
\overset{\mbox{\hspace{.1em}\resizebox{\tempa}{1ex}{$\frown$}}}{#1}
\endgroup}

\begin{document}
$\arc{AB}$, $\arc{ABC}$ and $\arc{P_1 P_2}$
\end{document}
```

[image: arcs]

The mnsymbol package contains a "filled spoon" symbol that may do the trick.  You can also create symbols using tikz, but that is a huge can of worms to tackle.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mnsymbol}
\usepackage{graphics}

\newlength{\tempa}

\newcommand{\segment}[1]% #1=symbols, as in \arc{AB}
{\begingroup% preserve \tempa
\settowidth{\tempa}{$#1$}%
\overset{\resizebox{\tempa}{!}{$\leftfilledspoon\hspace{-.2em}\rightfilledspoon$}}{#1}
\endgroup}

\begin{document}
$\segment{AB}$
\end{document}
```

[image: segment]

BTW, every time you load a package from CTAN you also get documentation, albeit scattered over many folders.  I recommend that you create shortcuts (links) to all these documents and put them into a single folder.

Comment: I see that you have been editing this file. You have added the "group" environment and you changed "\hspace{2pt}" to "\hspace{.1em}".  I like that the arc stretches to accommodate the width of the letters (or symbols) that indicate the endpoints of an arc. How is this conveyed in the code? I have been looking for web sites for a manual to explain some of the commands that you have used. What do the commands "\settowidth{\tempa}{$#1$}" and "\resizebox{\tempa}" instruct LaTeX to typeset?

Comment: You really need to get and read some basic LaTeX manuals.  (One of the things I like about TexnicCenter is its context help.)  em and ex change size with the font size, while pt is absolute.  \settowidth calculates the width of the text (second arg) and puts that value into length register (first arg).  \resizebox takes whatever is in the third argument and scales it to fit in a box whose width is he first argument and whose height is the second argument (! means preserve the aspect ratio).

Comment: Is there a manual that you would suggest? In the codes for conveying an arc and a line segment, you use "\tempa". If I am using both symbols in a file, should I have two different names for this command for setting a length? Is "tempa" an abbreviation?

Comment: The two best references are "Computers and Typesetting" by Knuth and "The LaTeX Companion" by Mittelback, Goosens et.al.  \tempa was defined/created by the \newlength command.  I could have used the predefined register \@tempdima but I try to avoid @ symbols.